# How can I implement the Apple Wallet app interface?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement the layout of the Apple Wallet app. It seems to have very sophisticated animations and interactions. Would I have to use a normal tableview or a collectionview to achieve those effects?

I gave it a go already with tableview animations and updating height on the cards but it was not quite as gentle as in the Wallet app.

EDIT:

What I tried so far on a button tap:

```
@IBAction func expandCards(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.expandedView.toggle()
        self.cardTableView.reloadData()
        self.cardTableView.beginUpdates()
        var index = 0
        for card in dataSource!.cards {
            self.cardTableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: expandedView ? .bottom : .top)
            index += 1
        }
        self.cardTableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Comment: show us what you have done so we can help with updates, and share what part exactly you want to replicate

Comment: StackOverflow is not a design service, nor a code debugging website. Please edit your question and include what you have tried, what error you're getting and what is the solution you'd like to get

Comment: Sure okay, if that's the case where I do ask a question like that? There is no error, I want to achieve an interface you have on the Wallet app.

Comment: show a gif or video of what you want to achieve

Comment: add your expected UI or animation Screenshot or GIF , it helps everyone to understands your basic layout requirements